# How can i add two variables between single quotes

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I have

```
function delImage(posteId,imagebinId) { 
    $.get("<?php  echo base_url('/Home/deletePostimage/') ?>"); 

    return false; 
}
```

i want to be like /Home/deletePostimage/posteId/imagebinId

i tried

```
$.get("<?php  echo base_url('/Home/deletePostimage/')+posteId+"/"+imagebinId ?>");
```

but it divide the two numbers

like posteId=5 imagebinId =2

the results will be

> /Home/deletePostimage/2,5

the params from

```
<a class="postimgsd" onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image ?')){delImage(<?php echo $value['id'],$get_images[0]['binId']; ?>); rmItem(<?php echo $i; ?>);}else{} ;  " >
```

Comment: just to be clear, you want it to be `/Home/deletePostimage/posteId/imagebinId` and not `/Home/deletePostimage/5/2` ?

Comment: @Shizukura posteId and imagebinId  are numbers, so it will be like /Home/deletePostimage/1220/3225

Comment: It would be easier to understand and work with your code if you separatw the javascript from the php, though keep it in the same file still. At the top of your file do `<?php $url = base_url(...) . postId . '/' . imgId; ?>`. Then lower in the file, in the js code: `$.get('<?=$url?>');`

Comment: You could also separate it further. There could be a bit of jscode immediately following the php bit that does `const theGetUrl = '<?=$url?>';` then in your actual js scripting it would be `$.get(theGetUrl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES6, you can do this with [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$.get(`<?php  echo base_url('/Home/deletePostimage/${postId}/${imagebinId}') ?>`);
```

Without ES6, there is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222264/2089675) that answers it, or use this:

```
var url = '/Home/deletePostimage/' + postId + '/' + imagebinId;
$.get("<?php  echo base_url('" + url + "') ?>");
```

---

Furthermore, the code that calls this function should actually be:

```
<a class="postimgsd" onClick="checkDeletion()" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function checkDeletion() {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image ?')) {
            var postId = <?php echo $value['id']; ?>;
            var imagebinId = <?php echo $get_images[0]['binId']; ?>;
            delImage(postId, imagebinId);
            rmItem(<?php echo $i; ?>);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ` $.get("<?php  echo base_url('/Home/deletePostimage/${posteId}/${imagebinId}') ?>");`  i got Home/deletePostimage/$%7BposteId%7D/$%7BimagebinId

Comment: @JDEV I forgot to mention this requires ES6. Does the environment support es6?

Comment: those the results i got, so, if it work for you, so the environment does not support es6

Comment: "<?php  echo base_url(" will end the line and not continue to ?>"); 
sorry for the bad explanation, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @JDEV no the entire expression is `"<?php  echo base_url(" + url + ") ?>"` which consists of three parts: `"<?php  echo base_url("`, `url` and `") ?>"` all joined with `+` which is used for string concatenation

Comment: i got http://127.0.0.1/fixx/ + url +    even the base_url didn't appeared

Comment: @JDEV, I'm not sure where you are getting those results from. In any case, I was missing single quotes for the url in php. Try that now

Comment: /Home/deletePostimage/12012545  which  1201 is posteid and  2545 is imageid, why there's not / between them ?

Comment: @JDEV I'm not sure why that's happening. I am not getting the same result. Make sure you are copying what I have above exactly as it appears otherwise I can't guarantee what results you get

Comment: not sure why, i tested your code in the chrome console and it work when i put simple values but not in my code, the parametre of that function are coming from php code `<a class="postimgsd" onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image ?')){delImage(<?php echo $value['id'],$get_images[0]['binId']; ?>); rmItem(<?php echo $i; ?>);}else{} ;  " >`

Comment: @JDEV that' the problem. You are not passing both parameters **separately** to the function. See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that PHP is processed on back-end before send the html to your user browser. That said, everything between php tags (`<?php ... ?>`) is rendered/processed before javascript even exists.

So if you put any JavaScript code inside your PHP code it won't work.

To make it work and be clean, do something like this:

```
function delImage(posteId,imagebinId) { 
    let url = "<?php  echo base_url('/Home/deletePostimage/') ?>";
    $.get(url + posteId + "," + imagebinId); 

    return false; 
}
```